# Remote call to invoke Parameterized job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to call a parameterized job in Jenkins by following [Remote API Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). It is triggering the job but is not passing the parameter value.

I have selected 'This is Parameterized Build' option for my jenkins job and have mentioned the token value and also the name of parameter correctly.

**Script:**

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/Ticket_Update/buildWithParameters -d token=auth --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"ticket", "value":"M-89"}]}'
```

Somehow it is not passing the value `M-89`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it did work, all I had to do was edit `buildWithParameters` to `build`.